# How do delete files with a certain name in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Iv'e got a directory **`%userprofile%\appdata\roaming\.minecraft\versions`** and in that directory is a whole heap of folders, I want a batch file to delete all the folder with forge anywhere in their name.

There are no sub files in these folders, but there are 2 files in each... I want anything in that directory with forge in its name deleted automatically with a batch file.

So delete all folders including forge in their name. I can't seem to do it.

I have tried googling stuff, but I can't remember everything I have tried... but here is some.

```
rmdir /s %userprofile%\appdata\roaming\.minecraft\versions

for /d /r . %d in (forge) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

Also, tried this (below) but it only listed the folders and files I want deleted.

`dir "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions" /s /b /d | find "forge"`

Comment: Is this a folder named "roaming.minecraft" or is "minecraft" a subfolder of "...\appdata\roaming\" --- "...appdata\roaming\minecraft\versions"?

Comment: yeah, its a sub folder ".minecraft" the directory is... "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming\.minecraft\versions                                                                        Im sorry i screwed up the question, edited it now

Comment: @Harry Is it true, since you want to delete any folder with the word "forge" in it, that anything within that folder with the name *forge* including files or other sub-folders will also be deleted and removed regardless of their name??

Comment: I want anything in that folder "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions" with the name forge including folders and files to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off & set "_target=%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions"
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s/b/a:d "%_target%\*forge*"')do echo/RMDir /q/s "%%~i"
```

- Or...

```bat
@set "_target=%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions"
@for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s/b/a:d "%_target%\*forge*"')do @echo/RMDir /q/s "%%~i"
```

**1)** Set target path to a variable

```bat
set "_target=%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions"
```

**2)** Use **`For /f`** with **`dir /s /b /a:d`** to list the desire folder:

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d "!_target!\*forge*"')...
```

**3)** See the **`for`** loop command and **`echo`** output...

```bat
')do echo/RMDir /q/s "%%~i"
```

**4)** If previous output is ok, remove **`echo`** command to delete the folder and possible sub folder/files recursively...

```bat
echo/RMDir /q /s "%%~i"
```

**For command line help, you can use `/?`:**

```bat
Set /?, For /?, RMDir /?
```

**On the internet, you can get more help on:**

- **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[RD / RMDir](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)**

Comment: Mate! you legend... U DID IT

Comment: @Harry Very nice/good to you! ThkX!

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell:

With the `-WhatIF` parameter, you can safely do a "test run" to see what folders the command will delete. If the items listed are the ones you want deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter.

```
$target = Join-Path $env:appdata '.minecraft\versions'
Get-ChildItem $Target -filter '*forge*'-Directory | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

[Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7)
[Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)
[Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7)
[Recurse](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/recurse/)

Comment: So, this **'$env:appdata '.minecraft\versions''** is like **'cd'** in cmd without concatenate?  work like: **"$env:appdata+'.minecraft\versions`''** ? Don't need to suppress/concatenate because space? The result path/string is the same: **`%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions`**?  Even with space present in the argument: **"$env:appdata '.minecraft\versions''**  ?

Comment: They are two seperate parameters to the `Join-Path` cmdlet. So the variable `$Target` becomes the full path to the target folder.

Comment: Yes, join Path1 +join Path2 i see now! Thank you! Good to know!

Comment: You can "construct" the path with other methods of string concatenation, but `Join-Path` can both add or subtract slashes between the two parameters to create a valid path:

Comment: Yes, I'm read it in your link, also works with reg/path… **`Join-Path -Path System -ChildPath *ControlSet* -Resolve`**

Answer (score 1):

When building this type of batch program, do yourself a favor and test that the files your parseing over correspond correctly with what your trying to achieve by replacing the end command with echo or a confirmation before running the final version

```
@Echo Off
PUSHD %userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions
For /R %%A in (*forge*) do (
    IF "%%~xA" == "" (
        Choice /N /C ny /M "Remove Folder? %%A"
        IF Errorlevel 2 (RMDIR "%%A")
    ) Else (
        Del /P "%%A"
    )
)
POPD
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and delete the files what have "forge" in the name, just enter *forge* in the search bar, then CTRL + A to select all the files (with file names including forge) and hit delete

Comment: And don't forget to use the star ( * ) character before and after the word  * forge *

Comment: How do i do that in a batch file?

Comment: If they are in the same folder use * wildcard to achieve that:

del *text*
Where text is string that filename contains.

Open notepad and write there:
del  * forge *

Save file as removeforge.bat

copy your saved "removeforge.bat" file into your  %userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\version

run removeforge.bat
and every file contains forge will be deleted.

Comment: DO NOT DO THE ABOVE

Comment: run the command with the `/P` switch, you'll see this does not work at all to limit deletions to files only containing Forge. `del /P * forge *`